# What is the best way to make photoluminescent resin with diffraction grating holographic effect?

Tags: epoxy-resin

I am creating a "Super Mario Invincibility Star" for my son. I've been working with resin now for roughly 5 years and have yet to see anyone create glowing resin with diffraction grating. I want to avoid more wasted time, money, product, patience, sanity, etc.

I have made holographic resin, and I have made glowing photo-luminescent resin. But I can't seem to pull off creating the two effects combined. My go-to resin so far has been Total Boat Tabletop 1/1 ratio. I have LIT extra fine glow powder pigment for the luminescence. And I did use diffraction grating sheets which I formed holographic silicone transfers, using Smooth-on Platinum 15 silicone mix.

Also, my man has 3D printed a model of the star with glow-in-the-dark filament, in hope that I could use it somehow in the creation of this star.

This is what I'm working with so far. But, I can't seem to put the puzzle together of what the best process would be. Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Arts & Crafts. I shortened the question a little and broke it into paragraphs for better readability. Hopefully, this will increase readership. But feel free to roll it back if you disagree with the changes. One thing that might be helpful --can you describe what difficulty you're running into when combining the photoluminescence and diffraction grating? As you indicate, you're not aware of others trying the combination. But people may have run into the symptoms before.

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is. Do you want to encase the 3D printed star in resin or do you want to cast a new star from glow-in-the-dark resin? And what exactly goes wrong when you try combining glowing resin with diffraction grating? Or asked differently: what is your expectation vs. the actual result? Please [edit] your post to add some more information.

Answer (score 3):

A diffraction grating effect will work for light from a point source or in a beam, probably reflected though transmitted light could work with very clear resin. Glow in the dark materials are diffuse sources that won't be suited to the grating. So you would have one effect in a darkened room, and a different effect under direct illumination. It's not clear whether that's desirable. You won't be able to use a grating surface to add sparkle to glow in the dark pigment, whether persistent (phosphorescent) or UV excited (fluorescent).